# align() won't work in case of using Box() in Kotlin JetPack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, alignment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anexK.png)can anyone help with this problem? Trying to compile this part of code, but it request imports,
but won't work after that also. Thanks. I just took that code from https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers, so i don't understand why it wont work, cause i imported all packages that i can. But i see some errors in import section. Sorry my English, thanks.

Box(
Modifier.align().fillMaxHeight().width(
50.dp
).background(Color.Blue)
)

I've tried to import that align, but it won't helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align content inside a `Box` you need to use `contentAlignment`:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .width(50.dp)
        .background(Color.Blue),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    //some code
}
```